# How to serialize values of nested json without using a wrapper class in Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring

I'm trying to consume a rest API call using Spring as below:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

Orders orders = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Orders.class).getBody();
```

The response I get is in following form:

```
{    
"orders":[{
    "field1": value1,
    "address":[{
        "city":"...",
        "state":"..."
    }]
}]
}
```

The Orders class has following fields:

```
Class Orders{
    String field1;
    Address address;

    // Getter / setter methods
}
```

Is it possible to map the values of "field1", and "address" directly to the fields inside Orders class? I cannot change the JSON response which I receive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think either one is going to work because OrderInfo has and array or orders, and Order has an array or addresses.

Comment: @faljbour So how do I serialize the response? Say that I just want to map each orders to an Order class having "field1", and "address" as its members..

Comment: see my answer, I am not sure that is what you are looking for, if not let me know